# Event listener on form

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am trying to get a JS event listener working and not sure if it is or isn't working. I have added an event listener to the form,  but even with 'preserve log' enabled, I cannot get a message in my console to confirm my code is working.

I ran a script to target the form id on mouseenter, and this worked fine, so I know the form id can be targetted, but with the 'submit' event, I am not seeing anything in the console.
 I have ensured that my script is running after the plugins script.

The form is from a WordPress plugin and I have included the bare bones of the html here.

```
<form method="post" id="tribe-tickets__registration__form" action="myurl/checkout" data-provider="tribe_wooticket">
    <div class="tribe-tickets__registration__grid"></div>
    <div class="tribe-tickets__registration__footer">
        <div id="tribe-tickets__notice__attendee-registration">
            <div class="tribe-common-b2 tribe-tickets-notice__content"></div>
        </div>

        <button class="tribe-common-c-btn tribe-common-c-btn--small tribe-tickets__item__registration__submit"
            type="submit">Save & Checkout</button>
        <button class="tribe-common-c-btn" type="submit">Save & Checkout</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
jpformsubmit = document.getElementById('tribe-tickets__registration__form');

jpformsubmit.addEventListener('submit', postGift);

function postGift(e) {
    console.log('Helloooo there!!!');
}
```

I also tried

```
window.onload = () => {
    document.getElementById('tribe-tickets__registration__form').addEventListener('submit', postGift);
};

function postGift(e) {

    console.log('Helloooo there!!!');
}
```

Comment: How did you initiate `jpformsubmit`? Is there maybe a missing `var`, `const` or `let`?

Comment: Hi, you are right, I didn't initiate it. Stupid error, however still no joy.  I am initiated it jpformssubmit but I still do not get a message in the console.

Comment: Rule of thumb, best place to do something is after document is fully loaded, the event document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{}). Also use debugger to see if your event is attached, or it throws something. Add a breakpoint into postGift function to see if it enters the function or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `e.preventDefault()` to your `postGift()` function.

Without it, the form submits, the page reloads, and the console log is cleared.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  document.getElementById('tribe-tickets__registration__form')
    .addEventListener('submit', postGift);
};

function postGift(e) {

  /* add this to prevent submit */
  e.preventDefault();
  
  console.log('Helloooo there!!!');
}
```

```html
<form method="post" id="tribe-tickets__registration__form" action="myurl/checkout" data-provider="tribe_wooticket">
  <div class="tribe-tickets__registration__grid"></div>
  <div class="tribe-tickets__registration__footer">
    <div id="tribe-tickets__notice__attendee-registration">
      <div class="tribe-common-b2 tribe-tickets-notice__content"></div>
    </div>

    <button class="tribe-common-c-btn tribe-common-c-btn--small tribe-tickets__item__registration__submit" type="submit">Save & Checkout</button>
    <button class="tribe-common-c-btn" type="submit">Save & Checkout</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried that and it did not improve things. I have 'preserve log' on anyway, so if it worked I would still see the message.

Comment: @JohnPaul The code snippet of the code you provided works. Something else must be wrong.